# Output in horizontal align instead of vertical align

Tags: java, netbeans

This is the coding that i have done. But the output is in horizontal align

This text file look like this:

1,2,8,4,5,6,7,7,

```
3,4,5,6,7,8,

5,6,7,8,9,9,

1,2,3,4,5,8,9,0,
```

I want the result to look like this :

```
2 8 4 5 6 7 7 

4 5 6 7 8

6 7 8 9 9

2 3 4 5 8 9 0
```

Code:

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));

        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;

while (scanner.hasNextLine())
{
    String currentline = scanner.nextLine();

    row++;

    String[] items = currentline.split(",");
    int[] intitems = new int[items.length];

    for (int i = 1; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        intitems[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
        System.out.println(intitems[i]);
        col = i;

    }
    col++;
    System.out.println("Column: " +col);
}

System.out.println("Row: " +row);


    }
```

I want to have the output to be vertical align instead of horizontal align. Is there a way to do it ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did everything right expect

if you change

```
 System.out.println(intitems[i]); <- by using this line, each element is written 
                                     in new line
```

to

```
System.out.print(intitems[i] + " ");<-by using this line, each element is written in 
                                      one line till the for loop is over
```

so you can edit this line

`System.out.println("\nColumn: " + col);`

to

```
System.out.pritnln(); <- in order the next set of elements be written in new line
```

your for loop section of your code become

```
       for (int i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {
            intitems[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
            System.out.print(intitems[i] + " "); <- change print to println
            col = i;

        }
        col++;
        System.out.println( ); <- get rid of the written info
```